# App sandboxing issue with Apple Mac app store

Tags: python, macos, sandbox, code-signing, entitlements

I am creating the entitlement keys for my app's sandbox.  I'm having some issues with the entitlement key `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.sbpl`.  There are five exceptions that I need to add to this key and they are `ipc-posix-sem`, `file-issue-extension`, `mach-lookup`, `file-write-create`, and `file-read-data`.  Because I am making this application outside of Xcode (I'm using Python), I have to manually create the entitlement file.  I already 'succeeded', but Apple doesn't seem to like my formatting.

Here is the original code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.sbpl</key>
    <string>
            (begin
                (allow ipc-posix-sem)
                (allow file-issue-extension)
                (allow mach-lookup)
                (allow file-write-create)
                (allow file-read-data))
        </string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After being rejected for `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.sbpl`, I made the following revision:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.sbpl</key>
    <array>
        <string>(allow ipc-posix-sem)</string>
        <string>(allow file-issue-extension)</string>
        <string>(allow mach-lookup)</string>
        <string>(allow file-write-create)</string>
        <string>(allow file-read-data)</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My question is this: Is my new formatting the correct way of using the `.sbpl` entitlement?  After tasting my app, it works with this new entitlement file, now all I need to know is if it is acceptable for Apple.

I found two examples of entitlement files from [here](https://github.com/samdmarshall/SDMMobileDevice/blob/master/Framework/SDMMobileDevice.entitlements) and [here](https://github.com/nikf/apple-app-sandbox/blob/master/garageband.txt), and I believe my file is setup appropriately after looking at them.

Answer (score 1):

I found another Sandbox entitlements [file in GitHub](https://github.com/samdmarshall/SDMMobileDevice/blob/master/Framework/SDMMobileDevice.entitlements) and your formatting looks correct to my eyes.

I think another problem may be is that you need to supply arguments after commands like "`mach-lookup`".  I'm looking at the [Apple Sandbox Guide unofficial documentation found here](https://reverse.put.as/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Apple-Sandbox-Guide-v1.0.pdf).

Comment: I see what you mean by adding arguments after the commands.  `mach-lookup` I got figured out.  I read the unofficial documentation you linked me to, and I have two questions about my commands and their arguments; 1. Do I need an argument after `ipc-posix-sem`? My console prints this when the key is inactive: `deny ipc-posix-sem /mp-qfg08qha`.  2. For `file-read-data` and `file-write-create`, do they need a path?  I don't see how I can do that because they change depending on user selected file paths or locations of files on the user's computer (such as `/Users/myname/Desktop/filename.png`)